# Can you Help me with Code

Tags: apex, code

```
Public static void opptyownermanagerupdate(Opportunity[] Opptylist)
{
   List<Opportunity> Opptylists = new List<Opportunity>();
   List<Opportunity> opptyToUpdate =new List<Opportunity>();
   Set<id> ownerid = new Set<id>();
   For(Opportunity op :Opptylists)
    {
    if(op.StageName=='ClosedWon'&& op.Order_Complete__c) 
     {
       If(ownerid != null && !ownerid.isEmpty())
       {
       ownerid.add(op.owner.id);
       opptytoUpdate.add(op);
       }
       }
       }
     Map<Id, string>  userMap= new Map<Id, string>();
     For(User oppOwner : [Select Id, Manager.Name from User where Id IN :ownerid ])
     {
      userMap.put(oppOwner.Id, oppOwner.Manager.Name);
     }

    For(Opportunity op: Opptylists)
     {
      op.Timestamped_Manager__c = usermap.get(op.owner.id);
     }
}
```

I have written the code above to update the `Timestamped Manager` field with the Opportunity Owner's manager name, but it is getting updated with Opportunity Owner's Id instead. What correction needs to be done here?

Comment: Is Timestamped Manager a lookup to User or a Text field for the name?

Comment: The code towards the end looks OK. If this is being called from a trigger `op.ownerId` would be better than `op.owner.id` as related objects are not populated in triggers. But as posted, this class will never do anything because it is iterating over the empty `Opptylists` rather than the `Opptylist` that is passed in. Can you check that in the code you are running and update your question?

Comment: I don't think it's ever going in that second if statement. What exactly are you trying to achieve with `!ownerid.isEmpty()`? Also `ownerid != null` it's always the case since you're instantiating it above - `Set<id> ownerid = new Set<id>();` so you don't have to check for that.

Comment: Timestamped manager is text field on Opportunity Object

Answer (score 1):

`op.Timestamped_Manager__c = usermap.get(op.owner.id);`  appears to be the culprit here.

You've stated that the Timestamped_Manager__c field is a text field, in which case you'd likely want to change that to a user lookup. In the standard salesforce UI, user lookups are always displayed by the name of the user.

If you want to keep the field as a textfield, you'll have to use op.owner.name (id that's available) or query for the name field first.

Answer (score 0):

Public static void Timestampedmanager(Opportunity[] Opptylist)
{
   List Opptylists = new List();
   Set ownerid = new Set();
   For(Opportunity op :Opptylists)
    {
    if(op.StageName=='ClosedWon'&& op.Order_Complete__c) 
     {
       If(ownerid != null && !ownerid.isEmpty())
       {
       ownerid.add(op.ownerid);

```
   }
   }
   }
 Map<Id, string>  userMap= new Map<Id, string>();
 For(User oppOwner : [Select Id, Managerid , Manager.Name from User where Id IN :ownerid ])
 {
  userMap.put(oppOwner.Id, oppOwner.Manager.Name);
 }

For(Opportunity op: Opptylists)
 {
  op.Timestamped_Manager__c = usermap.get(op.ownerid);
  system.debug('ssssssssssss'+op.Timestamped_Manager__c);
 }
```

}

I have modified the code , still its not working.The Time stamped manager field is empty.
I suspect op.Timestamped_Manager__c = usermap.get(op.ownerid); should be updated like 
op.Timestamped_Manager__c = usermap.get(op.ownerid).Manager.name

but when i do that its throwing error.

can you help.